# Nested cmake generator expressions are only partially evaluated

Tags: cmake

I try to use generator expressions for linking debug/release libraries like this:

```
list(APPEND LINK_LIBRARIES $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${LIBRARIES_RELEASE}> $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${LIBRARIES_DEBUG}>)
```

But only the inner generator is evaluated and the result of the expression is

```
$<1:/path/to/the/lib
```

The inner expression evaluated to 1, but the outer one did not work at all. It looks like a `>` is missing, but in the CMakeLists.txt it looks correct.

Comment: First, how do you find evaluation result of the generator expression? Note, that `message()` doesn't work for generator expressions. Second, does variable `LIBRARIES_RELEASE` contain single value or several (several paths)? In the latter case, each path should be wrapped with its own generator expression.

Comment: I find the value by looking into the generated library list in visual studio. ``LIBRARIES_RELEASE`` can container multiple paths, so maybe this should be broken up.

Comment: [from the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#whitespace-and-quoting): "_Generator expressions are typically parsed after command arguments. If a generator expression contains spaces, new lines, **semicolons** or other characters that may be interpreted as command argument separators, **the whole expression should be surrounded by quotes** when passed to a command. Failure to do so may result in the expression being split and it may no longer be recognized as a generator expression._". I'm guessing `LIBRARIES_RELEASE` is a list (has `;` in it).